# How to parse this string of data structure with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have the following sample data that are stored in a file:

```
[
  { "keys": ["val1", "val2"], "args": { "arg1": "val1", "arg2": "val2" } },
  { "keys": ["val1", "val2", "val3"], "args": { "arg": "val" } },
  { "keys": ["val"], "args": {} }
]
```

As you may realise, this is a `list` of `dictionaries`. Each dictionary has key `keys` contains arbitrary length of list and key `args` contains a dictionary

How could I parse this sample data back into `Python` object

```
with open('file_name') as file:
    source = file.read()

data = how_to_parse(source)

for arr in data:
    print(arr)

# Expected result
# { "keys": ["val1", "val2"], "args": { "arg1": "val1", "arg2": "val2" } }
# { "keys": ["val1", "val2", "val3"], "args": { "arg": "val" } }
# { "keys": ["val"], "args": {} }
```

Comment: Tks @AvinashRaj, that is correct answer. However as I am trying to learn `pyparsing`. I'd like to see an example using that library :)

Comment: Since your data looks like being JSON-formatted you might take a look at the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pyparsing wiki includes this example https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/parsePythonValue.py/31712649/parsePythonValue.py which I implemented at a time when `ast.literal_eval` was not yet available. Using this code, your expression can be parsed using:

```
print listItem.parseString("""[
  { "keys": ["val1", "val2"], "args": { "arg1": "val1", "arg2": "val2" } },
  { "keys": ["val1", "val2", "val3"], "args": { "arg": "val" } },
  { "keys": ["val"], "args": {} }
]""")[0]
```

which gives:

```
[{'keys': ['val1', 'val2'], 'args': {'arg1': 'val1', 'arg2': 'val2'}}, 
 {'keys': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], 'args': {'arg': 'val'}}, 
 {'keys': ['val'], 'args': {}}]
```

There are many more examples at https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples for your self-edification.

Comment: This example is explained in more detail in this presentation http://www.ptmcg.com/geo/python/confs/TxUnconf2008Pyparsing.html - mouse over the lower-right corner to see the presentation navigation icons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's great start for me to learn pyparsing

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing